# Permissions best practice

Tags: permissions, external-users

What is best practice for permissions where there are 10 different groups who would require different access permissions. For example, group 1 can only view document library 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

If the access between the different groups is mutually exclusive, create sites for each group. Sites are the most natural security boundary and most scalable, and easier to wrap your head around.

A more expedient option in the short term is to use one site, break inheritance on each library, and explicitly assign access to each group. This often becomes a maintenance headache in the real world as it's really difficult to determine who has access to what, and things risk getting out of sync.

Also there are limits to how many custom security boundaries you can have in a site. It's probably nothing to worry about given the numbers you're giving but something to keep in mind.

But both approaches are technically possible and feasible.